# QTableWidget чтобы был как QListWidget

Tags: qt, qt5, qtcreator

Как сделать чтобы `QTableWidget` выглядил как `QListWidget` но со столбцами!

Comment: А что Вы имеете в виду под `выглядил как` ? Таблица не может выглядеть как список.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то необходимо добиться эффекта представления QTableWidget, как QListWidget только с другим позиционированием элементов: не "сверху вниз", а "слева направо".

В данном случае можно использовать QListWidget, установив соответствующее свойство: setFlow(QListWidget::LeftToRight)

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QListWidget>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QListWidget w;
    w.addItems({"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"});
    w.setFlow(QListWidget::LeftToRight);
    w.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Не, Есть listwidget но он не поддерживает колонки а мне они нужны поэтому я хочу использовать tablewidget он поддерживает колонки я хочу сделать чтобы он был копией listwidget но сколонками